# Using JS to maintain the scroll position of a DIV upon postback... Need some help

Tags: javascript, html, postback, scroll

We are attempting to use JS to maintain the scroll position of a DIV upon postback of a standard FORM. There are several solutions online for ASP, PHP, etc... however we code in a proprietary CGI construct, thus those solutions have not worked for us.

I found this script on your page, written several years ago by Eric Pascarello (see below). It works **perfectly** for what we are trying to accomplish, less one major issue - it writes to a cookie, and we need it to write to a hidden field.

Through course of full disclosure, I am a software engineer and fairly well versed in various forms of scripting - however, I am embarrassingly TERRIBLE at JS. I am sure the solution is simple, and staring me in the face, but I am not sure what to change.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function(){ 
var strCook = document.cookie; 
if(strCook.indexOf("!~")!=0){ 
var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~"); 
var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!"); 
var strPos = strCook.substring(intS+2,intE); 
document.getElementById("'+divTest4+'").scrollTop = strPos; 
} 
} 
function SetDivPosition(){ 
var intY = document.getElementById("'+divTest4+'").scrollTop; 
document.title = intY; 
document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!"; 
} 
</script> 
<div id="'+divTest4+'" onscroll="SetDivPosition()" style="width:150px;height:200px;overflow:auto"> 
1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/> 
1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/> 
1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/> 
1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/> 
ERIC<br/> 
1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/> 
1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/> 
1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/> 
1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

G.C. Hutson
Sadien Intellectual Property 
gch@sadien.com 
(615) 869-0022 x 8100

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get at the value of the hidden field when the page is sent back to the server?  If so, you could replace `var strCook = document.cookie;` with `var strCook = document.myForm.hidElement.value` on the page.  Then, when the page is on the server, before serving the Request back to the client, you could render that hidden element with the value you just got on the server.